# How to set a mipmap icon on Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, layout, icons, floating-action-button, android-mipmap

My FAB is only showing the icon when I'm using a drawable resource, but not when I'm using a mipmap resource.

With a drawable resource:

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio Layout Editor with FAB drawable]

With a mipmap resource:

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio Layout Editor with FAB mipmap]

Comment: Could you try the `app:srcCompat` attribute instead of `android:src`?

Comment: Not work too :/

Comment: Same result using app or android

Answer (score 0):

Replace : android:src="@mipmap/your_mipmap"
with    : android:foreground="@mipmap/your_mipmap"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).